# Problems processing singly occurring nodes in xml

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I have a XML file. A node sometimes has one value and sometimes more than one value. I want to process it in groovy but I have trouble. please help me

```
def fields_srv=[]

tokens = context.testCase.name.tokenize('-')
def serviceName = tokens[0]
def responseXMLName = serviceName +"#Response"
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(responseXMLName)

for( node in holder['//fields'] ) 
    fields_srv.add(node)
```

for node "fields" with more than one value:

```
     <return>
        <billPageSize>10</billPageSize>
        <defaultBillStatementType>LAST_N_COUNT</defaultBillStatementType>
        <defaultLastN>10</defaultLastN>
        <fields>DOCUMENT_NUMBER</fields>
        <fields>CHEQUE_NUMBER</fields>
        <fields>DATE</fields>
        <fields>AGENTBRANCH</fields>
        <fields>NOTE</fields>
        <fields>CREDIT</fields>
        <fields>DEBIT</fields>
        <order>DESC</order>
     </return>
```

The script is OK

But for "fields" with one value:

```
     <return>
        <billPageSize>10</billPageSize>
        <defaultBillStatementType>LAST_N_COUNT</defaultBillStatementType>
        <defaultLastN>10</defaultLastN>
        <fields>DOCUMENT_NUMBER</fields>
        <order>DESC</order>
     </return>
```

It has Trouble because of:

```
"fields_srv" : [D, O, C, U, M, E, N, T, _, N, U, M, B, E, R]
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that holder['//fields'] returns element value instead of list with one element, when there is only one element "fields" in your xml. So this string value parsed as list of chars in loop. Add handler for this case or use something like this:

```
...
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(responseXMLName)

//will be a list, even if holder returns string value
def nodeList = []
nodeList.addAll(holder['//fields'])

for( node in nodeList) 
  fields_srv.add(node)
```

This code solves the problem